# order by in oracle with concatenating

Tags: oracle

i wrote a query and want to order by its number. I did thus but its not working. in this query pre_number are basically numbers 1,2,3,....,. I want order by this number, but its giving random values

```sql
select distinct NAME ||'--'|| pre_number as VALUE
from ftcon
where name ='ABC' and status = 'ACTIVE'
order by pre_number ;
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. `ORDER BY pre_number` is pretty much obvious - results will be sorted by `pre_number` value in ascending order. Can you illustrate what you're saying? Post some sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements, or - at least - a CTE).

Comment: Is your "random values" in the order of numbers as text, e.g. "1, 11, 2, 200, 3"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have stored the number as text. In this case I might get sorted in lexical order, i.e., first all the number beginning with `0`, then those with `1`, then with `2` etc, no matter how large the number is. E.g., 1, 120, 13, 250, 26, 33, 4, 51, 6. In this case convert it to a number for sorting or better, use a numeric type for this column.

```sql
select distinct NAME ||'--'|| pre_number as VALUE
from FTTH.FTTH_CONNECTIONS
where name ='ABC' and status = 'ACTIVE'
order by TO_NUMBER(pre_number);
```